# Android cannot resolve kotlin's suspendCoroutine

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin in an Android project with latest libs, but when I write suspendCoroutine this cannot be resolved, what am I missing?

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.3'
}
```

Create new project in Android Studio, add this to for example an Activity: `import kotlinx.coroutines.suspendCoroutine` -> cannot be resolved.

[Check the small sample on Github](https://github.com/mobilekosmos/KotlinResolve)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? Or at least show your code and setup.

Answer (score 1):

keep the implementation you already set, and

try:

```
import kotlin.coroutines.*
```

instead of:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.suspendCoroutine
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added classpath in your project level `build.gradle`

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$latest_version'
```

and implement dependecy in your app level `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$latest_version'
```